# What are the advantages of command line arguments in C?

Tags: c, command-line

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


}
```

I know that argc is the number of commands passed in command line, and in char *argv the arguments themselves. What is the optimal use of command line arguments instead of hard coding inside the program itself?

Comment: Well, obviously, it allows you to pass information into `main()` to configure the startup of your code, like passing a filename to open, or options that alter how your code behaves. NEVER hardcode numbers or filenames (unless it is a non-changing configuration file). Imagine having to re-compile your code just to read from a different data file?

Comment: If you accept input from command line, the information will be passed in command line arguments accessed via `argv[index]`, so your program will use different information on each invocation or display help, providing user with the variety of options, keeping it flexible and dynamic that is good, and this is how programs designed in Linux world. If you hard code the arguments, they become a variables :), and you don't allow any information to be passed dynamically to your program.

Comment: This seems to be an obvious question that a simple google search could have solved. I smell a conspiracy.

Comment: You could as well ask : "what is the advantage of using computer programs?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you've a command line `file_matcher` program, how are you going to use it? well, you've to pass the file names to the program that you want to match. You can not hard code them(means, you can not write the file names in the code file). cause if you hard code them, then you've to change the file names in the program code, each time, if for any reason the file name changes or you want to test new files.

Anyway I'm giving a piece of code I've written a long time ago to match two files. Play with it. And to run it call it like(assuming two files `file_1.txt` and `file_2.txt` are in the same dir as file_matcher):

```
> file_matcher file_1.txt file_2.txt
```

**And file_matcher.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char *get_charname(int ch) {
    if(ch == 0) return "Null";
    if(isspace(ch)) return "White space";
    if(iscntrl(ch)) return "Control Key";
    return "Others";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *f1, *f2;
    char ch1, ch2;
    int row, col;
    
    if(argc != 3) {
        if(argc == 1) printf("Missing file names\n");
        else if(argc == 2) printf("Missing a file name\n");
        else printf("Too many files\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    f1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(f1 == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    f2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if(f2 == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
        fclose(f1);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    row = 1;
    col = 1;
    while(fscanf(f1, "%c", &ch1) != EOF) {
        if(fscanf(f2, "%c", &ch2) == EOF) {
            printf("Too less data in \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
            printf("Matching stopped at (row, col): (%d, %d)\n", row, col);
            fclose(f1);
            fclose(f2);
            exit(1);
        }
        
        if(ch1 != ch2) {
            printf("Miss match at (row, col): (%d, %d)\n", row, col);
            
            if(isgraph(ch1)) printf("In \"%s\" found '%c'(ascii value: %d)\n", argv[1], ch1, ch1);
            else printf("In \"%s\" found '%s'(ascii value: %d)\n", argv[1], get_charname(ch1), ch1);
            
            if(isgraph(ch2)) printf("In \"%s\" found '%c'(ascii value: %d)\n", argv[2], ch2, ch2);
            else printf("In \"%s\" found '%s'(ascii value: %d)\n", argv[2], get_charname(ch2), ch2);
            
            fclose(f1);
            fclose(f2);
            exit(1);
        }
        
        if(ch1 == '\n') {
            row++;
            col = 1;
        }
        else col++;
    }
    if(fscanf(f2, "%c", &ch2) != EOF) {
        printf("Too much data in \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
        printf("Matching stopped at (row, col): (%d, %d)\n", row, col);
        fclose(f1);
        fclose(f2);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" matched succesfully\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
    
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Like, this program, many other programs are designed to take input from command line...

I hope, now you understand the reason behind it....

Comment: This answer is a little over-blown. You couldn't have just passed in a couple of `int`s and did a for-loop showing how it changes the behavior of the program?

Comment: @Andy, actually I wanted to make OP interested in some real useful application...cause, some normal example won't make the effect as this example could do...besides (s)he may be already know how to use command line args...

Answer (score 1):

Think of command line tools like `ls` or `cp` or `mv` in *nix command line environments (`dir`, `copy`, `move` and `rename` in MS command line environments).  Sure, you could make each program ask for inputs with a prompt:

```
$ cp
> source file name: foo.c
> target file name: bar.c
```

which works in an interactive session, but not in a script or batch session, such as

```
for file in *.c *.h
do
  cp $file backups/$file.bak
done
```

And even in an interactive session, it’s just plain *faster* to blap out

```
$ cp foo.c bar.c
```

rather than wait for a prompt.  It also makes it easier to deal with variable numbers of parameters, like

```
$ cp *.c *.h src
```

which copies all source and header files to a `src` subdirectory.

This isn’t unique to C - almost all programming languages have some way of receiving arguments from the runtime environment directly (either from a command line or some other mechanism).